# Writing @value in javadoc brackets remove - Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

I would like to write javadoc in Eclipse.
I have this piece of code:

```
private int variable;
```

When I want to add @value parametar in Eclipse above line I get {@value} instead of @value. When I want to add @author, I get output without {} brackets, as I want. How can I get @value without brackets?

Answer (score 0):

Since the `@value` tag appears in running text, it should be in braces. It is not a tag like `@author`, which occurs at the end and basically considers the text up to the next (braceless) tag as its parameters.

So Eclipse's suggestion is correct. Why do you want to use that tag without braces?

The Javadoc tool will replace `@value` tags with the value of the constant it documents (if no parameter is given) or with the value of the constant mentioned in the parameter. For example:

```
/** The value {@value}. */
public static int aConstant = 1;

/** 
 * Does something.
 * @param aValue should be {@value #aConstant}.
 * @return 42
 */
public int aMethod(int aValue) {
    ...
}
```